# How to typecast wxObject to wxVariant?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a map of wxObject..but i want to typecast it to wxVariant.

```
void MWDataViewTable::InitColumnValues(wxString targetcolumn,wxString sourcecolumn , std::map<wxObject,wxObject> srctargetvalue)
{
    wxVariant srcvalue;
    wxVariant tgtvalue;
    int srccolumnpos = GetColumnPosition(sourcecolumn);
    int tgtcolumnpos = GetColumnPosition(targetcolumn);
    int rows = m_rowdataList.size()-1;  //without header
    for(int i=0;i< rows;i++)
    {       
        GetValue(srcvalue,i,srccolumnpos);
        tgtvalue = (wxVariant)srctargetvalue[srcvalue] ;// typecasting
        SetValue(tgtvalue,i,tgtcolumnpos/*toggle-column*/);
    }

}
```

In the highlighted line i am doing the typecasting..but that is giving me an error that says "Error 1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const wxObject'"
this error is coming in **xstddef.h** file.
i dont have any idea why this is happening or if i am typecasting it wrongly.
HELP please..!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `map<wxObject, wxObject>` in the first place, this is just a bad idea and I don't see any circumstances in which it would be useful. And, of course, you can't cast a `wxObject` object (not pointer or reference) to `wxVariant` at all. What are you really doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `std::map`, the `key values are generally used to sort and uniquely identify the elements`.

In your code both the key and value are of `wxObject` type. 
The `wxObject` class doesn't seems to overload a less than operator method ( I have no idea as to what these wx objects are).

`std::map` requires a `less operator` method to perform the comparison required for sorting the key values.
So you should either pass your own comparison function to the std::map that would compare two wxObjects.

The template container std::map takes the compare function as the third agument.

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
           class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
           > class map;
```

Compare is a binary predicate that would have the follwing definition in your case:

```
bool MyCompare( const wxObject& , const wxObject&)
{
  \\Compare logic that returns true or false
}
```

You can have your own map that will be using this compare method:

```
typedef std::map<wxObject,wxObject,&MyCompare> MyMap;
MyMap srctargetvalue;
```

Comment: Can you try creating a function wrapper with std::function and pass that?

std::function<bool(const wxObject&,const wxObject&)> myFunction = MyCompare;  And pass myFunction to map

Comment: typedef std::map<wxObject,wxObject,&MyCompare> MyMap; this wont work.. so what i did was to enclose the compare function in a atruct.. and the i gave the struct in the map..it worked properly,,thanx for your help buddy..:)